# How to pass json from c# to mongodb stored js

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

We are trying to post json string from c# to mongodb stored javascript using driver ver 1.8

Here is my js function :

```
function addCorporate (json) {
    db.Corporate.save(json);

   /* obj = JSON.parse(json);
    if(obj.corporateName) {        
        db.Corporate.save(obj);
    }
    */
}
```

Note: We tried to run it with commented code as well

C# code :

```
var CorporateData="{\"corporateName\":\"a\"}";

MongoClient client = new MongoClient(hostedWebConnectionString);
            MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
            MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("myDb");

            BsonValue bv = db.Eval("addCorporate", CorporateData);
            BsonValue bv1 = db.Eval(bv.AsBsonJavaScript.Code, CorporateData);
```

The above code gives error as follows:

```
Command '$eval' failed: exception: Error: can't save a null
at Error (<anonymous>)

at DBCollection.save (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:486:15)

at _funcs1 (_funcs1:2:18) at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:486 (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: Error: can't save a null\n    at Error (<anonymous>)\n    at DBCollection.save (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:486:15)\n    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:2:18) at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:486", "code" : 16722, "ok" : 0.0 })
```

If we uncommnet the lines in js function and comment the 1st line then we get following error:

```
"Command '$eval' failed: exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
at Object.parse (native)

at _funcs1 (_funcs1:4:16) (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token    at Object.parse (native)    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:4:16)", "code" : 16722, "ok" : 0.0 })
```

Note: We also tried to parse it as BsonValue i.e

```
var bsonString = (BsonValue)CorporateData;
```

but still it gives error.

Please suggest any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mention the c# driver which you are using to save data to mongodb

Comment: HI Abdul, I have used legacy driver ver 1.8

Comment: check my following answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [mongocsharpdriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver), then you have to change your object `CorporateData` to `BsonDocument` before saving, check out the following code snippet(I am currently using this in my project),

```
var CorporateData="{\"corporateName\":\"a\"}";
var yourCollectionName="CorporateInformation";

MongoClient client = new MongoClient(hostedWebConnectionString);
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("myDb");
var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(CorporateData);
var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(yourCollectionName);
collection.Insert(document);
```

Hope this helps :)

**UPDATED:** To use javascript function defined in mongodb. **IT IS NOT RECOMMENDED BECAUSE IT MEANS THAT YOU ARE SHIFTING YOUR BUSSINES LOGIC TO DB. OVER THE TIME IT WILL BE DIFFICULT TO MANAGE.**

You have not provided function name to your javascript function, change it to following,

```
function addCorprate(json) {
    db.Corporate.save(json);

   /* obj = JSON.parse(json);
    if(obj.corporateName) {        
        db.Corporate.save(obj);
    }
    */
}
```

and your code should work as it is.

Comment: This doesn't uses stored javascript , I want to use store js function and insert it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to write name of function over here , but i have given name in my code and updated 1st post over here as well.

Comment: Yea I know we are shifting the logic to DB as we have skilled ppl with mongodb skills and would prefer them to handle this.